# Google Drive API Http Client Timeout C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Im currently working on a C# software, that zips some files and then  uploads them to my google drive.

I followed this tutorial for the Google Drive API: [How to upload a file to Google Drive with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/)

The Problem is that the upload fails because the HTTP client gets a timeout.

Does anyone know something?

is it Maybe the "Text/Plain" in the file creation on the drive?

```
private static string pathToServiceAccountKeyFile = @"C:\Users\X\Downloads\File.json";
        private const string serviceAccountEmail = XXX";
        private static string uploadFileName = @$"{zipFilesStorageDir}\{date}.zip";
        private const string directoryID = "XXX";


private static void FileUpload()
        {
            uploadFileName = @$"{zipFilesStorageDir}\{date}.zip";


            // Load the Service account credentials and define the scope of its access.
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(pathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
                            .CreateScoped(DriveService.ScopeConstants.Drive);



            // Create the  Drive service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });


            // Upload file Metadata
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = date + ".zip",
                Parents = new List<string> { directoryID }
            };





            string uploadedFileId;
            // Create a new file on Google Drive
            using (var fsSource = new FileStream(uploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
                var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
                request.Fields = "*";
                var results = request.Upload();

                if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
                }

                // the file id of the new file we created
                uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial shows how to upload a text file so it uses the mime type of

```
var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
```

For uploading a zip i should think that would do the trick.

```
var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "application/zip");
```

From the docs for [File.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

[image]

What i think is happening is you are telling it that you are uploading a  text file but you are actually uploading a zip so thats why its not working.  However I think its a little strange that its throwing a http client timeout.

Let me know if that doesnt work for you.

Comment: I'm not shure if that fixed it, because it still doesnt work on my pc.
Anyway, it seem like the problem is my machine/network. I uploaded the programm to an remote pc an there it works. dont know why, but I wont touch it.
Thank you anyway for your time and help.

Edit:
Also I commented the Stackoverflow link to your reply unde the Video, but it didnt took it. Sry for the Search

Comment: Check your firewall it may be blocknig the call

Comment: Already tried that with all Firewalls, but its probably our Network service.